# Springboot with Mongodb Criteria.orOperation doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-aggregation

I am trying to create one OR operation with Criteria in MongoDB with Spring-Boot, this is my code:

```
TypedAggregation<Ficha> agg = newAggregation(Ficha.class,    
   // match(Criteria.where("parte.nome").regex(".*"+ query+".*")),
   // match(Criteria.where("parte.nome").regex(".*"+ query+".*").orOperator(Criteria.where("parte.documentos.numero").regex(".*"+ query+".*"))),
   // match(Criteria.where("parte.documentos.numero").regex(".*"+query+".*")),
   group("parte.nome").first("parte.nome").as("nome"),
   project().and("nome").previousOperation().and("nome").as("nome")
```

If I uncomment line 1, it works (search only in `parte.nome`).

If I uncomment the last line, it works too (but searches only in `parte.documentos.numero`).

If I uncomment the middle line, it doesn`t work. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement it as:

```
TypedAggregation<Ficha> agg = newAggregation(Ficha.class,    
   match(new Criteria().orOperator(
        Criteria.where("parte.nome").regex(".*"+ query+".*"),
        Criteria.where("parte.documentos.numero").regex(".*"+ query+".*")
    )),  
   group("parte.nome").first("parte.nome").as("nome"),
   project().and("nome").previousOperation().and("nome").as("nome")
);
```